# Prompting Dialog Box to Have User Enter Information without ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcmap, arcgis-engine, arctoolbox, add-in

Working with the ArcGIS family v10.1 on Windows 7.

So, I have this vision for a GIS project that does the following:

1. User opens up ArcGIS Explorer (ideally) or ArcMap (still fine), or I guess even an external website (least ideal) and loads in my project file.
2. It pulls up this map I've made- let's say it's a shapefile of a
   city, with house/parcels linked to a database of information, like
   address, owner, year built, and number of windows.
3. They either click one button or hit a hotkey and up pops a dialog
   box where they can enter, say, 1234 main street, and click ok.
4. Then, without the user having to do anything, ArcExplorer/Map zooms
   to that parcel/house and also selects and displays, say, all other houses that
   intersect a circle with a diameter of 300 years, and outputs out a list of the houses in that selection circle.
   There's a lot more. but I just want to know if this is something that can be done. In the ideal it wouldn't take a ton of sophisticated coding; it doesn't really even need to be fully functional, just a proof of concept.

While writing this I've been looking around the internet, and it seems like ArcGIS engine is something I would need? Any way the above could be done without ArcGIS Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create this as a ArcGIS Add-In using ArcObjects.  Add-Ins elements (such as buttons) can be loaded into ArcMap (see [creating custom button or tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements_using_add_ins/0001000001ms000000/) walk through).

Coding wise your button click event will have to call a [select feature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000088000000) procedure where you can link your text box value as the query filter where clause value.  You can then use various [ArcGIS Snippets](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000010000000) to zoom to the selected feature, buffer the point, and select surrounding features based on spatial intersection.